# Safely execute arbitrary code as a sub-query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to run text input as a sub-query of an object.

Examples for better understanding:

```
//input: "all();"
collection.all(); //actual code ran

//input: "where({age: 10}).limit(10);"
collection.where({age: 10}).limit(10); //actual code ran
```

All of the possible functions that the sub-query may contain is unknown, so they cannot be filtered out.

The most simple solution would be to use eval:

```
function run(subquery) {
    return eval('collection.' + subquery);
}
```

However this allows for code injection eg: `run('all();alert("dough!");');`

**How can I safely execute arbitrary code as a sub-query?** (Node.js specific answers are also welcome);

Comment: If you parse the input to something more like `var obj = {fn : 'where', params : {age > 10}};` you could do something like `collection[obj.fn](obj.params)`

Comment: @adeneo functions can be chained, also I don't want to restrict the API in any way.

Comment: Bracket notation can still be chained, but I think you have to either just eval the string, and somehow make it safe to eval by doing some validation or sandboxing, or you have to parse the string and use it in something like bracket notation to execute the functions.

Comment: @adeneo On second thinking the bracket notation is a great idea, the hard part comes when user input has strings that contain `()'";,` etc and that breaks the parsing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, it would require you to build a small parser that could split the string and figure out what parts are function names, what parts are arguments, and what kind of arguments etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VM module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) which allows you to execute JS in a sandboxed environment.

For an example, see the [vm.runInNewContext](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename) example.

Depending on what variables you need, the safest way to go should be to copy those variables into a new context, to disallow the script to modify your existing context.

Note: This is specific to Node.JS and won't work in the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working thanks to @adeneo's idea. I parse the input into an array like this:

```
//where({age: 10}).limit(10);
var track = [{fn: 'where', args: {age: 10}}, {fn: 'limit', args: 10}]
```

After I can use the bracket notation:

```
for (var key in stack) {
    var val = stack[key];
    result = result[val.fn].apply(this, val.args);
}
```

The method I used to parse the initial execute was:

```
function init() {
    var stack = [];
    function push(fn, args) {
        stack.push({
            fn: fn,
            args: args
        })  
    };
    return {
        foo: function () {
            push('foo', arguments);
            return db;
        },
        bar: function () {
            push('bar', arguments);
            return db;
        },
        stack: function () {
            return stack;
        }
    };
}
var db = init();
db.foo(1).bar({a: 5}).foo(false).stack();
```

One downside to this is that it requires you to define every possible method (foo and bar).